# How can I remove() div after fadeOut/setTimeout

Tags: jquery

When user clicks a button it calls a function that creates a div after body tag, shows it and then fade it out after 1sec. But how can I remove() this div and keep the fadeOut animation?

I tried this:

```
function myFunc(){
    jQuery('body').prepend("<div class='myDiv'>Hello World!</div>");
    $( ".myDiv" ).show( "slow", function() {});
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.myDiv').fadeOut('fast');
        $(".myDiv").remove();
    }, 1000);

}
```

But this solution doesnt keep the fadeOut animation. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('.myDiv').fadeOut('fast');
        $(".myDiv").remove();
    }, 1000);
```

try to use

```
$('.myDiv').fadeOut(1000, function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: But this will break the logic of the original code which is intended to start hiding the `div` element in one second after it has showed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myDiv').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(".myDiv").remove();
});
```

The function is called when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `div` in callback of the `$.fadeOut()`.

Also I'd suggest to run `setTimeout()` inside the callback of `$.show()` so you'll ensure the sequence of all the operations.

```js
$(function() {
  var $div,
      onShow,
      onHide;
  
  $('body').prepend("<div class='myDiv'>Hello World!</div>");
    
  $div = $(".myDiv");
  
  onShow = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $div.fadeOut('fast', onHide);
    }, 1000);
  };
  
  onHide = function() {
    $div.remove();
  };

  $div.show("slow", onShow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.myDiv').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}, 1000);
```